# How to style a graph of isotope decay data automatically so that vertices and edges correspond to half-lives and decay probabilities?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, physics, entity

For teaching purposes I am trying to create some plots of radioactive decay chains, whereby each node on the graph represents the isotope with a color corresponding to the isotopes stability and with an edge weight that corresponds to the probability of decay.

All of this information is available as collated entity data for isotopes from Wolfram:

```
IsotopeData["Properties"]

{"AtomicMass", "AtomicNumber", "BindingEnergy", "BranchingRatios","DaughterNuclides", "DecayEnergies", "DecayModes","DecayModeSymbols", "DecayProducts", "ExcitedStateEnergies","ExcitedStateHalfLives", "ExcitedStateLifetimes", "ExcitedStateParities", "ExcitedStateSpins", "ExcitedStateWidths", "FullSymbol", "HalfLife", "IsotopeAbundance", "Lifetime", "MagneticMoment", "MassExcess", "MassNumber", "Memberships", "Name", "NeutronNumber", "Parity", "QuadrupoleMoment", "QuantumStatistics", "Spin", "Stable", "StandardName", "Symbol", "Width"}
```

One example in the [Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IsotopeData.html) gives a neat way of extracting all daughter nuclides and plotting them as a graph:

```
DaughterNuclides[s_List] := DeleteCases[Union[Apply[Join, Map[IsotopeData[#, "DaughterNuclides"] &, DeleteCases[s, _Missing]]]], _Missing];
ReachableNuclides[s_List] := FixedPoint[Union[Join[#, DaughterNuclides[#]]] &, s];

verts = ReachableNuclides[{Entity["Isotope", "Uranium232"]}];
DaughterNuclidesQ[s1_,s2_] := (s1 =!= s2 && MemberQ[DaughterNuclides[{s1}], s2]);
RelationGraph[DaughterNuclidesQ, verts, Sequence[VertexLabels -> {Entity["Isotope", "Bismuth210"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 210], "Bi"}], Entity["Isotope", "Bismuth212"] -> 
Row[{Superscript["", 212], "Bi"}], Entity["Isotope", "Lead204"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 204], "Pb"}], Entity["Isotope", "Lead206"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 206], "Pb"}], Entity["Isotope", "Lead208"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 208], "Pb"}], Entity["Isotope", "Lead210"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 210], "Pb"}], Entity["Isotope", "Lead212"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 212], "Pb"}], Entity["Isotope", "Mercury200"] -> 
Row[{Superscript["", 200], "Hg"}], Entity["Isotope", "Mercury204"] -> 
Row[{Superscript["", 204], "Hg"}], Entity["Isotope", "Mercury206"] -> 
Row[{Superscript["", 206], "Hg"}], Entity["Isotope", "Polonium210"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 210], "Po"}], Entity["Isotope", "Polonium212"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 212], "Po"}], Entity["Isotope", "Polonium216"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 216], "Po"}], Entity["Isotope", "Radium220"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 220], "Ra"}], Entity["Isotope", "Radium224"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 224], "Ra"}], Entity["Isotope", "Radon216"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 216], "Rn"}], Entity["Isotope", "Radon220"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 220], "Rn"}], Entity["Isotope", "Thallium206"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 206], "Tl"}], Entity["Isotope", "Thallium208"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 208], "Tl"}], Entity["Isotope", "Thorium228"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 228], "Th"}], Entity["Isotope", "Uranium232"] -> Row[{Superscript["", 232], "U"}]}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.65, ImageSize -> 300, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]]
```

This gives the following graph:

[image: Graph of Decays]

How can I modify this code so that the color of each node corresponds to half-life and the thickness of the lines corresponds to decay probability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I struggled with this for a while, but have come up with the following solution which although slow is suitable for creating images for teaching. I use `IsotopeData` to get hold of half-lives and decay probabilities and then use this to style edges and to make graphics for the vertices. Perhaps somebody may find it useful (the reason I am posting). If anyone has suggestions or improvements please feel free to modify! The code is somewhat slow I think because of calling all of the data from Wolfram, but seems to work ok for my purposes.

I have used the solution from this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66923/match-colors-to-plot-themes/66982#66982) to get the plot colours of the scientific theme.

```
decayPlot[isotopename_] := Module[{DaughterNuclides, ReachableNuclides,   DaughterNuclidesQ, isoSymbol, verts, halflives, minmaxlog, shapecalc, vertshapes, branchratio, edgerules, edgestyle,colorvals},
colors = (("DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Scientific", ListLinePlot])) /. Directive[x_, __] :> x); 
DaughterNuclides[s_List] := DeleteCases[Union[Apply[Join, Map[IsotopeData[#, "DaughterNuclides"] &, DeleteCases[s, _Missing]]]], _Missing];
ReachableNuclides[s_List] := FixedPoint[Union[Join[#, DaughterNuclides[#]]] &, s];
DaughterNuclidesQ[s1_,s2_] := (s1 =!= s2 && MemberQ[DaughterNuclides[{s1}], s2]);
isoSymbol[isotope_] := Row[{Superscript["", IsotopeData[isotope, "MassNumber"]],IsotopeData[isotope, "AtomicSymbol"]}];
verts = ReachableNuclides[{Entity["Isotope", isotopename]}];
halflives = (QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[#["HalfLife"], "s"]]) & /@verts;
minmaxlog = Log[MinMax[Select[halflives, # != Infinity &]]];
colorvals={0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1};
shapecalc[isotope_] := Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thickness[0.06]], If[QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[isotope["HalfLife"], "s"]] == Infinity, White, 
  ColorData["Pastel"][1 - (Log[QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[isotope["HalfLife"], "s"]]] - minmaxlog[[1]])/Total[minmaxlog]]],, Disk[], Black,Text[Style[isoSymbol[isotope], FontSize -> 6], {0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 20];
vertshapes = Map[# -> shapecalc[#] &, verts];
branchratio[edge_] := QuantityMagnitude[edge[[1]]["BranchingRatios"][[Position[edge[[1]]["DaughterNuclides"], edge[[2]]][[1, 1]]]]]/100;
edgerules = EdgeRules[RelationGraph[DaughterNuclidesQ, verts]];
edgestyle = Map[(#[[1]] \[DirectedEdge] #[[2]] ->If[branchratio[#] < 0.05, {Dashed,Thickness[0.002]}, {Thickness[0.01]}]) &, edgerules];
Legended[RelationGraph[DaughterNuclidesQ, verts, VertexLabels -> None, VertexShape -> vertshapes, VertexSize -> 0.6, PlotRangePadding -> 0.65`, ImageSize -> 300, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", EdgeStyle -> edgestyle, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"], {SwatchLegend[Join[{White}, Map[ColorData["Pastel"][#] &, colorvals]],Join[{"Stable"}, Map[Quantity[ScientificForm[Exp[minmaxlog[[2]] - #*(minmaxlog[[2]] - minmaxlog[[1]])], 3], "s"] &, colorvals]]],LineLegend[{Directive[{colors[[1]], Thickness[0.01]}],Directive[{colors[[1]], Dashed, Thickness[0.005]}]}, {"Probable Decay", "Improbable Decay"}]}]]

decayPlot["Uranium235"]
```

This then gives:

[image: Decay Uranium 235]