# Color the labels given by Label in Plot consistently with the colour of the corresponding function

Tags: plotting, labeling, plot-themes

Consider the following toy example:

```
With[{
  data = Table[
    Labeled[Sin[n x], n],
    {n, 1, 5}
    ]
  },
 Plot[
  data,
  {x, 0, Pi},
  PlotRange -> All
  ]
 ]
```

which produces the following plot:
[image]

In cases like this, it may be hard to figure out what label corresponds to what plot.
Is there an easy way to have the labels coloured consistently with the colour of the corresponding line?
This would mean in this example to have the `1` coloured blue, the `2` coloured orange, etc.

Comment: In such a case a usual `Legend` is much better.

Comment: @corey979 I agree for this toy example, but sometimes you have data which is well described with Labeled, except for some of the lines that overlap on the right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the color of the label using `Style` and assign the color of the curves to be the same as the color of the labels. Further you can control the font face, boldness and size, etc...

First define a list of colors

```
colors = {Black, Orange, Red, Purple , Blue}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use `colors` and `Style` to assign the color of the text (text arbitrarily set to Bold and font size 14 as an example).

```
With[
 {
    data = Table[Labeled[Sin[n x],
                 Style[n, Bold, 14, colors[[n]]]], {n, 1, 5}]
  },
 Plot[data, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> colors]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Update

In order to use the default colors (described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54486/how-to-access-new-colour-schemes-in-version-10)) replace `colors` with `ColorData[97, "ColorList"]`

```
With[
 {
  data = Table[Labeled[Sin[n x],

     Style[n, Bold, 14, ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[n]]]],
    {n, 1, 5}]
  },
 Plot[data, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: this is the straightforward solution, yes. I was however hoping for a solution that wouldn't force me to specify my own color scheme for the plot, instead using the default one used by Mathematica for the plot

Comment: @glS Update that answers your new question.