# How can I evaluate only a single step of a recursive function?

Tags: functions, function-construction, symbolic, recursion

Let's say have a simple recursive function for the Fibonacci sequence

```
f[0] := 1
f[1] := 1
f[n_] := f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]
```

but I want to see how it will expand in a given number of steps, but not all the way through. For example, let's say that I want to take `f[n+1]` and use my rules to expand it into `f[n] + f[n-1]`, and then expand those to `f[n-1] + 2*f[n-2] + f[n-3]`.

Ideally I'd like to know if there's a way to do something like *apply the expansion twice* to get to the second result, but doing so manually in two steps would be fine as well.

The reason why I'm interested in doing this is that I'm using Mathematica to sort of help me with proofs where I just need to manipulate lots of expressions using simple transformation rules, which means I need to see the steps in between, not just the final result (I hope this makes sense.)

Comment: `i = 0;f[0] := 1;f[1] := 1;f[n_] /; i++ < 2 := f[n - 1] + f[n - 2];f[8]`

Comment: Related question: [How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/334/142)  Mr.Wizard's answer is particularly nifty, although it won't work unmodified for the present question due to the vagaries as to what exactly constitutes "one step".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One way is to use an extra argument that acts as a switch.

```
Clear[f];
f[0] = 1;
f[1] = 1;
f[n_, True] := f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]
```

Example:

```
f7 = f[7, True]

(* Out[329]= f[5] + f[6] *)
```

To proceed another step, can do a replacement.

```
f7 /. f[aa_] :> f[aa, True]

(* Out[330]= f[3] + 2 f[4] + f[5] *)
```

Can use `Nest` to repeat this `n` times.

```
Nest[# /. f[aa_] :> f[aa, True] &, f7, 3]

(* Out[332]= 4 + 2 f[2] + 2 (3 + f[2]) + f[3] *)
```

Comment: Nice Nest trick

Comment: @belisarius Thanks. Pity what I had to do to those birds though..

Comment: Wouldn't this work with `->` instead of `:>`? I'm sitll a little fuzzy on those two and never sure which one to use when.

Comment: @Jakob Arnold You don't need my permission, just try it. In truth I don't know myself (and no time to check just now).

Answer (score 9):

If we are willing to confine ourselves to functions like the example `f` which:

1. is defined using `DownValues` only, and
2. has no special attributes such as `HoldAll`, etc.

... then the following lifting function might be useful:

```
ClearAll[stepper]
SetAttributes[stepper, HoldAll]
stepper[f_Symbol] :=
  Module[{rules, g}
  , rules =
      Rule @@@ Cases[DownValues[f], (l_ :> r_) :> ((Hold[r] /. f -> g) /. _[rr_] :> Hold[l, rr])]
  ; Function[Null, Defer[#]&[Unevaluated@# /. rules] /. g -> f, HoldAll]
  ]
```

`stepper[f]` returns an evaluator function which, when applied to an expression, evaluates the expression normally except that the rules associated with `f` are not invoked recursively.  So, for example:

```
sf = stepper[f];


f[3] // sf
(* f[1] + f[2] *)

f[1] + f[2] // sf
(* 1 + f[0] + f[1] *)

1 + f[0] + f[1] // sf
(* 3 *)


f[n+1] // sf
(* f[-1+n] + f[n] *)

f[-1+n] + f[n] // sf
(* f[-3+n] + 2*f[-2+n] + f[-1+n] *)

f[-3+n] + 2*f[-2+n] + f[-1+n] // sf
(* f[-5+n] + f[-4+n] + f[-3+n] + 2*(f[-4+n] + f[-3+n]) + f[-2+n] *)
```

Evaluation using `stepper[f]` proceeds as follows:

1. The `DownValues` of `f` are copied and transformed so that all right-hand-side occurrences of `f` are replaced with an inert symbol (this occurs once).
2. An expression is evaluated by applying the transformed down-value rules, forestalling any recursive application of `f` since it no longer appears in any of the rule bodies.
3. The result is wrapped in `Defer`.
4. `f` is restored in place of all occurrences of the inert symbol within the deferred expression.

The implementation of `stepper` is complicated somewhat by the need to dodge some inconvenient variable renaming within scoping constructs and to prevent early evaluation of the right-hand-sides of rules.

This methodology could be applied to a more elaborate evaluator that handles symbol attributes, `UpValues`, and so on.  But the evaluator complexity grows rapidly with these extra features and the exhibited form of `stepper` might be useful enough as is.

Answer (score 7):

The answers are great. I wanted to add that the problem you are trying to solve fits way better with replacement rules than function definitions, so switching to those can provide a more understandable answer

```
Clear[f];
frules = {f[0 | 1] :> 1, f[n_] :> f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]};

f[7] /. frules (* same as f[7]//ReplaceAll[frules] *)
f[7] /. frules /. frules
Nest[ReplaceAll[frules], f[7], 3]
(* f[5] + f[6] *)
(* f[3] + 2 f[4] + f[5] *)
(* f[1] + f[2] + f[3] + 2 (f[2] + f[3]) + f[4] *)
```

Now, if you already begin with the function `f` defined.

```
f[0] := 1
f[1] := 1
f[n_] := f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]
```

You can extract the rules by using `DownValues` as @WReach did.

```
frules = DownValues[f];
```

But then you have to take care to avoid `f` applying its own definitions automatically. You can either replace the `f` symbol in the rules by another one that isn't defined. You can also do the replacements inside a `Block` where `f` becomes undefined and wrap the results in `Hold` (or equivalent). You can clear `f`. Personally I would perhaps do something that I haven't seen on the site (or not much, or don't recall) so it may be interesting to mention: block a dialog

```
Block[{f}, Dialog[]];
```

And now fall back to the original answer

```
f[7] /. frules (* same as f[7]//ReplaceAll[frules] *)
f[7] /. frules /. frules
Nest[ReplaceAll[frules], f[7], 3]
```

When you are done, `Return[]` (or more robustly, `ExitDialog@Unevaluated@Abort[]`

Answer (score 4):

If you're using M10, you could do it with `Inactivate` (which formats more nicely in Mathematica than it does here in plain text.)

```
Inactivate[f[7] /. #, f] &[DownValues[f]]
(* Inactive[f][5] + Inactive[f][6] *)
```

Then `Nest` it:

```
Clear[step];
SetAttributes[step, HoldFirst];
step[e_] := step[e, 1]
step[e_, n_] := Inactivate[Nest[Function[{x}, x /. #], e, n], f] &[DownValues[f]]

step[f[7], 2]
(* Inactive[f][3] + 2 Inactive[f][4] + Inactive[f][5] *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Not paticularly elegant for reading but with minimal programming effort we can write

```
f[0] = a;
f[1] = b;
f[k_] := HoldForm[f[k - 1] + f[k - 2]]

ff[n_] := NestList[ReleaseHold, f[n], n - 1]
```

Example

```
ff[7] // Column
```

$\begin{array}{l}
 f[7-1]+f[7-2] \\
 (f[5-1]+f[5-2])+(f[6-1]+f[6-2]) \\
 (f[3-1]+f[3-2])+2 (f[4-1]+f[4-2])+(f[5-1]+f[5-2]) \\
 b+3 (f[2-1]+f[2-2])+3 (f[3-1]+f[3-2])+(f[4-1]+f[4-2]) \\
 3 a+7 b+4 (f[2-1]+f[2-2])+(f[3-1]+f[3-2]) \\
 7 a+12 b+(f[2-1]+f[2-2]) \\
 8 a+13 b \\
\end{array}$

Regards,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 1):

```
h[f[0]] := f[0];
h[f[1]] := f[1];
h[f[x_]] := f[x - 1] + f[x - 2];
nst[n_, num_] := 
 Total@Nest[Cases[#, f[y_] :> h[f[y]], Infinity] &,{f[n]}, num]
```

Testing:

```
Table[nst[10, j], {j, 0, 9}] // TableForm
```

[image]