# Implement recursion one step at a time with a function of more than one variable

Tags: symbolic, recursion, variable-definitions, difference-equations

i am trying to implement a recursive difference equation step by step, by implementing rules, similar to Rojo's method in this thread: [How can I evaluate only a single step of a recursive function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63256/how-can-i-evaluate-only-a-single-step-of-a-recursive-function)

But the rules are not applied to my function, I think because it contains more than one variable. This is important for the answer, since one of the variables is integrated over. The other variable is decremented, which is what I want to iterate step-wise:

```
Clear[f, frules];
frules = {f[n_, x_] -> (n - 1) x^n Cos[x] f[n - 1, x] + Integrate[Sin[x] f[n - 1, x], x]};
f[3] /. frules
f[3] /. frules /. frules
f[m] /. frules
```

This just gives $f[3]$, or $f[m]$, without implementing the recursion.

I'm specifically interested in the symbolic expressions after 1,2,...p steps. How to start from a given integer value $m$ and write the expression after $p$ decrements of 1?

The mathematical expression should be well posed because I can incrementally increment the function, with a given starting value:

```
f[n_, x_] := (n - 1) x^n Cos[x] f[n - 1, x] + Integrate[Sin[x] f[n - 1, x], x]
f[0, x] = 1;
```

Gives well defined functions for f[1], f[2], f[3], etc. E.g. $f[1] = -Cos[x]$ ,  $f[2] = \frac{1}{2} (1 - 2 x^2) Cos[x]^2 $ , etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule won't fire because of the signature issue (`f[3]` vs. `f[3,x]`). And there will be no end to the recursion as currently configured.

It's not clear what are wanted for the edge cases where `n` is less than 2 or the number of steps to take is 0. Taking a couple of guesses, it could be set up like so. I use a third argument to give the number of steps for the recursion. Also this uses memoization to avoid reevaluations.

```
myf[2, x_, _] = x^2* Cos[x];

myf[n_Integer, x_, k_Integer] /; n > 2 && k >= 1 := 
 With[{next = myf[n - 1, x, k - 1]}, 
  myf[n, x, k] = (n - 1)* x^n* Cos[x]* next + 
    Integrate[Sin[x]*next, x]]
```

Here are a few steps for the case `n=5`. More steps will not change the result since the last one bottomed out on the recursion.

```
In[59]:= Table[myf[5, x, j], {j, 0, 3}]

(* Out[59]= {myf[5, x, 
  0], \[Integral]myf[4, x, 0] Sin[x] \[DifferentialD]x + 
  4 x^5 Cos[x] myf[4, x, 
    0], \[Integral](\[Integral]myf[3, x, 0] Sin[
           x] \[DifferentialD]x + 3 x^4 Cos[x] myf[3, x, 0]) Sin[
      x] \[DifferentialD]x + 
  4 x^5 Cos[
    x] (\[Integral]myf[3, x, 0] Sin[x] \[DifferentialD]x + 
     3 x^4 Cos[x] myf[3, x, 0]), 
 30 x + (3 x^2)/32 - 5 x^3 + x^5/4 + x^6/32 - (13 Cos[x]^2)/54 - (1/
  1296)(99 + 1341200 x - 54 x^2 - 913440 x^3 + 183600 x^5 - 
     17496 x^7 + 972 x^9) Cos[2 x] - (3367 Cos[4 x])/442368 - (
  626425 x Cos[4 x])/663552 + (751 x^2 Cos[4 x])/6144 + (
  73585 x^3 Cos[4 x])/27648 - 87/512 x^4 Cos[4 x] - 
  1685/768 x^5 Cos[4 x] + 3/64 x^6 Cos[4 x] + 27/32 x^7 Cos[4 x] - 
  3/16 x^9 Cos[4 x] + 6365/9 x^4 Cos[x] Sin[x] + 
  244195/486 Sin[2 x] - 11/72 x Sin[2 x] - 28345/27 x^2 Sin[2 x] - 
  189/4 x^6 Sin[2 x] + 27/8 x^8 Sin[2 x] + 
  4 x^5 Cos[
    x] (-(1/16) (-7 + 960 x + 2 x^2 - 160 x^3 + 8 x^5) Cos[
       x] - ((57 + 320 x - 54 x^2 - 480 x^3 + 216 x^5) Cos[3 x])/
     1296 + 60 Sin[x] + 3/8 x Sin[x] - 30 x^2 Sin[x] + 
     5/2 x^4 Sin[x] + 
     3 x^4 Cos[
       x] (2 x^5 Cos[x]^2 - 1/8 (-1 + 2 x^2) Cos[2 x] + 
        1/4 x Sin[2 x]) + 20/243 Sin[3 x] - 5/72 x Sin[3 x] - 
     10/27 x^2 Sin[3 x] + 5/18 x^4 Sin[3 x]) + (1797355 Sin[4 x])/
  7962624 - (1933 x Sin[4 x])/36864 - (215635 x^2 Sin[4 x])/110592 + 
  87/512 x^3 Sin[4 x] + (24955 x^4 Sin[4 x])/9216 - 
  15/128 x^5 Sin[4 x] - 189/128 x^6 Sin[4 x] + 27/64 x^8 Sin[4 x]} *)
```

I hope this is along the lines of what you are seeking.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I think that basically solves it. I wish I checked my syntax before posting, because my code actually worked fine after I changed f[3] to f[3,x]. Your code did the decrement and left the answer in terms of an integral which is what I was after (which my code also does after fixing). Your code also automates the decrement procedure a variable $k$ times, unlike my manual implementation. Thanks and I'll accept. As a side note, I noticed that the answer your code gives, and the answer Bob Hanlon's code gives below are different, though so far as I can tell the input is the same?..

Comment: The code from Bob Hanlon has a different initial condition. I had missed this condition in my original reading of the question.

Comment: I think there's an issue here! Here is your code, and @BobHanlon 's code, for the same initial (boundary) condition, and the same n=2: `myf[0, x_, _] = 1;
myf[n_Integer, x_, k_Integer] /; k >= 1 :=  With[{next = myf[n - 1, x, k - 1]}, 
   myf[n, x, k] = (n - 1)*x^n*Cos[x]*next + Integrate[Sin[x]*next, x]];
myf[2, x, 2]
Part[(seq =  RecurrenceTable[{f[n] == (n - 1) x^n Cos[x] f[n - 1] + 
        Integrate[Sin[x] f[n - 1], x], f[0] == 1}, f, {n, 2, 2}] // 
    FullSimplify) , 1] ` They really do give different results for the function, and **not** by a constant...

Comment: I.e. one gives $Cos[x]^2/2 - x^2 Cos[x]^2$ , and the other gives $-(-1 + x^2) Cos[x]^2$