# Is there a way to convert a string to a Table indicator?

Tags: string-manipulation, list-manipulation, expression-construction

I have a list like this:

```
list = {"k1","k2"}
```

I want to use the elements in the list as `Table` **indicators**:

```
Table[k1 + k2, {ToExpression@list[[1]], 1, 2}, {ToExpression@list[[2]], 1, 2}]
```

but I get an error:

> Table::write: Tag ToExpression in ToExpression[list[[1]]] is Protected.

Is there a way to get the right answer like:

```
Table[k1 + k2, {k1, 1, 2}, {k2, 1, 2}]
```

> {{2, 3}, {3, 4}}

Comment: Something like `With[{kk1 = ToExpression@list[[1]],   kk2 =ToExpression@list[[2]]}, Table[k1 + k2, {kk1, 1, 2}, {kk2, 1, 2}]]`. See the _Possible Issues_ section of `Table` :)

Comment: duplicates or closely related: [76917](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76917/5478), [20719](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20719/5478)

Comment: @Öskå Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Table[k1 + k2, Evaluate@{ToExpression[list[[1]]], 1, 2}, 
 Evaluate@{ToExpression[list[[2]]], 1, 2}]
(* {{2, 3}, {3, 4}} *)
```

Or

```
Table[k1 + k2, {#, 1, 2}, {#2, 1, 2}] & @@ ToExpression[list]
(* {{2, 3}, {3, 4}} *)
```

Comment: Tank you very much for your excellent answer.