# Append fixed value to random selection of list

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation, assignment

(This question might be an application of [this other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-do-i-evaluate-only-one-step-of-an-expression), but there might be another solution specific to this application that I'm not aware of.)

I am currently in a situation in which (in a `For` loop) I am appending the current value to one of several lists, chosen randomly. (The lists themselves contain nonrandom values.) The basic structure of

```
RandomChoice[{AppendTo[listA,value], AppendTo[listB,value], 
    AppendTo[listC,value], AppendTo[listD,value],...}]
```

works, but it seems highly repetitive to have a random choice of appending the same value. The obvious thing to do would be to reverse the two functions, giving

```
AppendTo[RandomChoice[{listA, listB, listC, listD,...}],value]
```

but then `AppendTo` tries to append `value` to the `RandomChoice` function instead of its output. However, if I surround the `RandomChoice` with an `Evaluate`, it instead comes up with an error of "{1,2} is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed". But if `Evaluate` is not the outermost function within the `AppendTo`, it tries to append `value` to that outermost function (e.g. `ReleaseHold`). Surrounding each list with `Defer` produces some results that, to me, are truly weird, returning an error of "listB [or whichever one was randomly chosen] is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed" -- even though I have previously defined those lists as variables with values! Using `Map` and `Apply` also don't work, as the results come in completely unevaluated, leaving me with the first situation. These pretty much exhaust all possibilities that I know of. Are there any possibilities that I'm not aware of? (I'm looking for something which can be done in a single expression, if it's at all possible.)

(Using v10.2)

Comment: What if you did something like `AppendTo[lists[[RandomInteger[{1, Length@lists}]]], value]`, where `lists = {listA, listB, listC, listD,...}`?

Comment: It errors with "{listA,listB,listC,listD} in the part assignment is not a symbol".

Comment: Once `listA`, `listB`, etc. are defined, you define `lists = {listA, listB, listC, listD,...}`, and then it should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comment by @march that using an indexed list would simplify things nicely.  However, if we wish to press on with named lists then one way would be to create a list of functions that express the possible `AppendTo` operations and then to evaluate a randomly chosen function from that list.

For example, starting from:

```
listA = {1, 1, 1};
listB = {2, 2, 2};
listC = {3, 3, 3};
listD = {4, 4, 4};
```

We can generate a list of appending functions:

```
fns = Cases[Hold[listA, listB, listC, listD], l_ :> (AppendTo[l, #]&)]

(* { AppendTo[listA, #1]&, AppendTo[listB, #1]&,
     AppendTo[listC, #1]&, AppendTo[listD, #1]& } *)
```

We choose one of those functions randomly...

```
f = RandomChoice[fns]

(* AppendTo[listC, #1] & *)
```

... and then use it to update the corresponding list:

```
f[999]

(* {3, 3, 3, 999} *)
```

We can then verify that the selected list, and only the selected list, has been changed:

```
listA
(* {1, 1, 1} *)

listB
(* {2, 2, 2} *)

listC
(* {3, 3, 3, 999} *)

listD
(* {4, 4, 4} *)
```

If we are only interested in the result of the random append operation without actually updating the corresponding variable, then all we need to do is use `Append` instead of `AppendTo`:

```
Append[RandomChoice[{listA, listB, listC, listD}], 999]

(* {3, 3, 3, 999} *)
```

Comment: This works pretty much like I wanted, although I would use `f:=...` rather than just `f=...` for my specific case. The one thing that I'm confused about is: how does the `Hold` get broken?

Comment: The `Cases` expression transforms each element of the `Hold` expression into a function.  It is at that point that each list variable gets notionally moved out of the `Hold` and into a `Function`.  A function definition is also a held context, so the list variable is still not evaluated.  It is only when the function is called that the list variable finally appears in a context in which it is evaluated.

Comment: I don't know your full context, but if you are using `f := ...`, then I'd probably recommend that you use `f[] := ...` instead.  This is a matter to style rather than necessity.  I'd be suprised, for example, if `{f, f}` returned a list with different elements.  But getting different elements from `{f[], f[]}` is unsurprising.  Again, this is just a question of convention rather than a language requirement.  You might also consider something like `f[n_] := RandomChoice[fns][n]`.

Answer (score 3):

With, for instance,

```
listA = {1, 2}; listB = {3, 4}; value = 5;
```

the command

```
RandomChoice[{AppendTo[listA, value], AppendTo[listB, value]}]
```

appends `value` to all lists and then selects one of them, as can be seen from.

```
{listA, listB}
(* {{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 5}} *)
```

As an alternative, use

```
RandomChoice[{listA, listB} = Map[Join[#, {value}] &, {listA, listB}]]
```

which is more compact for a large set of lists.  It too appends `value` to each list before selecting one.

However, if you actually wish to append `value` only to the randomly selected list without changing the values of the original lists, use the suggestion by [march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29734/march) in a comment above.