# Partial evaluation of symbols with non-inert OwnValues

Tags: evaluation

Background: there are many, many questions here about the infamous ::setraw error. More often, than not, they have to do with repeated assignments to symbols.

Here's the code:

```
ls = {a, b, c};
Evaluate[ls] = {1, 2, 3};
```

This command will work only once. It got me thinking, **how, once `a`, `b`, and `c` already have `OwnValues`, would one go about reassigning them, by using only the symbol `ls` and not referencing `a`, `b`, or `c` directly?**

What about injecting them into `Block`, `Module` and related?

Of course, all sorts of combinations of `OwnValues`, `Hold`, etc, that came to my mind, at one point or another need an `Evaluate` or similar at some point, but `Evaluate` immediately drills down to `{1, 2, 3}`.

I post one approach that seems to work as a self-answer, but it feels rather hackish. I'm pretty sure, there are better ways to go about this.

Comment: One relatively simple way is to use injector pattern: `Hold[ls]/.OwnValues[ls]/.Hold[res_]:>(res = {1,2,3})`. More generally, one can do `Unevaluated[code]/.OwnValues[sym]`, in this case it will be `Unevaluated[ls = {1,2,3}] /. OwnValues[ls]`. This form will be easy to generalize to several symbols in need of partial evaluation.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin The first time this question struck me, was when I wanted to do something like `Block[Join[list1,list2], code]`, but I see now, that this would drastically shift the goalposts. Maybe, when I encounter this use case again, I'll ask a new question. The injector pattern is much simpler than I thought, though, thanks.

Comment: PS I just *know* there're extensive threads here on evaluation control, that are very relevant. If anyone recalls them, they ought to be linked.

Comment: The `Block` thing can also be done relatively easily. If you pass them directly, thin something like this: `ClearAll[block];
SetAttributes[block, HoldAll];block[symlists : {__Symbol} ..., code_] :=
  Join @@ Apply[Hold, Unevaluated[{symlists}], {1}] /. 
   Hold[syms___] :> Block[{syms}, code];`. Example: `{x, y, z, t} = {1, 1, 1, 1}; block[{x, y}, {z, t}, Print[x, y, z, t]]`. If you store them in variables, add an extra step like the one I described above.

Comment: @Leo Neat. But also demonstrates, that there'll need to be a very specific injector-pattern-thing for every different use case. Still, that's more than enough examples to work off.

Comment: *But also demonstrates, that there'll need to be a very specific injector-pattern-thing for every different use case* - sometimes, but not always. Some of such functions can be made quite general.

Answer (score 1):

My MWE involves using Mr. Wizards [`step`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/26956) function:

```
SetAttributes[step, HoldAll]

step[expr_] :=
  Module[{P},
    P = (P = Return[#, TraceScan] &) &;
    TraceScan[P, expr, TraceDepth -> 1]
  ]
```

and some hackish nonsense

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Set},
  ClearAttributes[Set, SequenceHold]; 
  With[{HoldForm = Sequence},
    # = {4, 5, 6}] &@step[ls]
]
```

which survives, thanks to `Set`'s attribute of `HoldFirst`. When I have the need to modify so many built-ins, I begin to feel uncomfortable.