# Pick complexes out from a list

Tags: functions, function-construction, complex, functional-style

Consider the assumptions

```
$Assumptions = {Element[a,Reals], Element[z,Complexes]}
```

I'm looking for a test, to be applied on `a` and `z`, that gives `True` if the argument is a complex number such as `a` and `False` if it's real such as `z`.

The aim is to use this test in a replacement in this way

```
set = {a, z, x};
set /. (x_ :> img /; test[x])
(* {a, img, x} *)
```

An example is

```
set /. (x_ :> img /; Simplify[NotElement[x, Reals] && Element[x,Complexes]] === (NotElement[x, Reals]))
```

It is based on the fact that

```
Simplify[ Element[z,Reals] ]
```

remain unevaluated.

Is there another possible test that doesn't rest on this (and, possibly, simpler and without `If` and similar)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following uses [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) to *loosely* check if a symbol has a definition  using a particular domain.

```
ClearAll[symbolDomainQ];
SetAttributes[symbolDomainQ, HoldFirst];

symbolDomainQ[s_Symbol, domain_] :=
 Or @@ Nor @@@ (Through@{FreeQ[s], FreeQ[domain]}[#] & /@ $Assumptions)
```

With

```
$Assumptions = {a ∈ Reals, z ∈ Complexes, m ∈ Matrices[{4, 4}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]}
```

Then

```
{symbolDomainQ[a, Reals], symbolDomainQ[z, Complexes], symbolDomainQ[m, Reals]}
```

> ```
> {True, True, True}
> ```

```
symbolDomainQ[m, Matrices]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
symbolDomainQ[a, Complexes]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

This only works if the symbols have not been assigned values. When they are assigned values `$Assumptions` changes so that it is not searchable for that symbol.

```
a = 1;
$Assumptions
a=.
```

> ```
> {True, z ∈ Complexes, m ∈ Matrices[{4, 4}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]}
> ```

It would be nice to have a built-in function that could check against the assumptions and work with or without a symbol having a value.  Perhaps you should make a suggestion to WRI.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, another practical solution, at least in my case, is this: starting from `$Assumption`, create a list with all real parameters, and after, using `Complement`, get a list with the complex parameters. With this list it's easy to create the test function just using `MemberQ`

Comment: FWIW the definition of `$Assumptions` has not changed, only the way it evaluates.  You can pull the held form using my `step` function from http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121

Comment: That is an interesting function. +1

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways, e.g.:

```
f[x_] := With[{ri = ReIm /@ N[x]}, 
  ri /. {{_, 0} :> False, {_, _} :> True}]
```

Testing:

```
r = RandomReal[1, 10];
c = Complex @@@ RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
test = Join[r, c][[RandomSample[Range@20]]];
Thread[{test, f[test]}] // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Hi ubpdqn, Thanks for your reply. Actually I'm looking for something that can work with symbols defined in the $Assumptions, not just with numbers. I've modified my question in order to be clearer.