# Puzzled regarding avoiding evaluations and using results of computations as functions

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, compile, hold

### What did I do before?

I seem not to be able to understand MMA's evaluation scheme. I read some posts like [Preventing Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856177/preventing-evaluation-of-mathematica-expressions) or [a MathGroup post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/v9Z-kSKx_ew) where the topics of evaluation prevention are discussed. Unfortunately, I am not able to fully understand it and use it for my specific purpose. Direct help (or hints to other *useful* posts) are appreciated.

### What's the problem?

I use a quite complicated (and messy) function `generate` to generate further functions. This function could output

```
2 ev[c, k, kF, LatticeSize]
```

for example. The evaluation to find the new function is costly and I don't want to repeat it but afterwards directly work with the above evaluation result, so I use (notice the `Set` notation instead of `SetDelayed`)

```
(* "…" symbolize parameters to generate that are not of importance here for understanding the problem. *)
fun[c_,k_] = generate[…]
```

Now it is possible to evaluate `fun[5,6,1.5,4]` for example and get a result. As soon as I define `ev` to be a compiled function (performance is of interest for me), the `generate` function tries to evaluate `ev` directly. How can this be prevented and instead `fun` be made a function that is directly dependent on the compiled (and not evaluated function) `ev`?

### Bare minimum code

```
generate[] := 2 ev[c, k, kF, LatticeSize];
ev = Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}, {kF, _Real},{LatticeSize, _Integer}}, If[i == j, kF/\[Pi], With[{dist = Min[Abs[i - j], LatticeSize - Abs[i - j]]}, 1/\[Pi]*Sin[kF dist]/dist]], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Evaluation of

```
fun[c_, k_, kF_, LatticeSize_] = generate[]
```

should show the problem now.

Comment: Could it be an option to temporarily unset `ev` while you define `fun`?  `Block[{ev}, fun[...] = generate[]]`.  The `fun` definition would not contain the compiled functions in this case, only the `ev` symbol. This should not be a problem *for as long as you don't change the value of `ev`*.

Comment: @Szabolcs Embarrassing I didn't see the solution myself. Many thanks, it - of course - works like a charm. If you want to answer the question in a full post and not a comment, I will accept it, making clear for others the question is resolved.

Comment: I'm not sure why the close vote. This doesn't seem to be a trivial mistake, and if it's found easily in the documentation, then I have been reading the wrong docs :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can temporarily unset `ev` while creating the definition for `fun[...] = ...`

```
Block[{ev},
  fun[c_, k_, kF_, LatticeSize_] = generate[];
]
```

The resulting definition for `fun` will contain `ev` now:

> ```
> fun[c_,k_,kF_,LatticeSize_]=2 ev[c,k,kF,LatticeSize]
> ```

Thus you will need to maintain the value of the global variable `ev` for this to work.

What if we want to inline the value of `ev` into the definition?  We can do this:

```
Block[{CompiledFunction},
  fun[c_, k_, kF_, LatticeSize_] = generate[];
]
```

This will prevent the errors from `CompiledFuction` by disabling it during the definition process.  The resulting definition will be

> ```
> fun[c_,k_,kF_,LatticeSize_]=2 CompiledFunction[...][c,k,kF,LatticeSize]
> ```

Note that even if you don't disable it temporarily, the errors can be safely ignored. The definition will still be usable, if ugly.

---

Unfortunately, all these are really just hacks.  They are convenient hacks for the problem at hand, but they do not generalize well.

A more general problem would be inlining `ev` without knowing its value beforehand. Here I made use of the fact that the value of `ev` was a `CompiledFunction`. I knew precisely what to disable using `Block` to prevent unwanted evaluation.

In order to solve this more general problem, you may need to operate on the `DownValues` of `fun` and use advanced methods such as [the Trott–Strzebonski in-place evaluation technique](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/12).

I would be very interested to see a nice and general solution to this more complicated problem without resorting to such esoteric techniques.  *EDIT:* See @MrWizard's solution.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I wouldn't miss it because I am familiar with this undocumented form of `Function`. I would be looking for the first argument if I don't see it, so I would notice the comma.  I added it for the benefit of those who haven't seen this syntax before.  They may not notice the comma because it's so tiny ...

Comment: I know, I just had to tease you. :D

Answer (score 4):

This kind of partial evaluation can be done using my `step` function from [How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-do-i-evaluate-only-one-step-of-an-expression/1447#1447)

```
Function[Null, fun[c_, k_, kF_, LatticeSize_] := #, HoldAll] @@ step[generate[]]

?fun
```

> ```
> fun[c_, k_, kF_, LatticeSize_] := 2 ev[c, k, kF, LatticeSize]
> ```

The advantage of this over `Block` is that you do not need to know in advance what `ev` is.

Comment: I know the `Null` is not necessary, but it's so easy to miss that tiny comma ...

Comment: I keep my promise and accept Szabolcs' answer but definitely +1 here, too. ;)

Comment: I don't remember step off the top of my head, but doesn't that cause overhead in terms of evaluating `generate[]` more than once, since there's a call to trace and so on?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP `step` is only used to create the definition of `fun`; once that is defined it is as if you had typed in in by hand.  There is no overhead of any signification *while* defining `fun` either as evaluation stops as soon as the definition of `generate[]` is pulled.  That was one of the primary requirements for `step` before I figured out how to do it.  You could do the same thing in this case with `Hold[generate[]] /. DownValues[generate]` but I find `step` both cleaner and more general.

Comment: I still have some doubts, but I'm really not sure how to check it rigorously. (output of `TracePrint[step[f[...]]]` vs. `TracePrint[f[...]]` bugs me a bit). There might also be the issue, that to get from `generate[]` to `2 ev [...]` may take more than one `step`, but that's unanswerable without details of `generate[]`.