# Extract DownValues used in function evaluation

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

Is there a convenient way to find out which [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) is used when calling a function? As an example, consider the following function:

```
abs[Complex[0,n_]] := Complex[0,Abs[n]]

abs[n_?NumberQ] := Sign[n] n

abs[n_?NumericQ] /; MemberQ[{-1,0,1}, Sign[n]] := Sign[n] n

abs[x_] /; Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[x] := -x

abs[x_] := x
```

which is just some random code. Now, I want to know which [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) fired when I evaluate `abs[N@I]`? Obviously, this example is simple enough that I can figure out which [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) would fire by inspection, assuming the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) occur in the order listed above. However, suppose there are many more [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues), or suppose you don't to spend time perusing the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) to figure out which one would fire for a particular input. Is there some simple function that will give me which [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) has fired?

Comment: Somewhat related: [(334)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/334/121)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple utility function that I use all the time:

```
SetAttributes[ExtractDownValues, HoldAll]

ExtractDownValues[sym_[args__]] := ExtractDownValues[sym,args]
ExtractDownValues[sym_,args__] := Cases[
    DownValues[sym], _[h_, _] /; MatchQ[Unevaluated[sym[args]], h]
]
```

For your example we find:

```
ExtractDownValues @ abs[N @ I]
```

> {HoldPattern[abs[n_?NumberQ]] :> Sign[n] n, HoldPattern[abs[x_]] :> x}

I keep the full list of matching [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) because the real matching [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) can be hard to determine syntactically if any of the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) use [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition).

Answer (score 4):

This could be useful.

I attempted to handle [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html); maybe it can be cleaned up some.

```
SetAttributes[capture, HoldFirst]

capture[expr : h_[___]] :=
  Module[{dv, rls, i = 1, cond},
    SetAttributes[cond, HoldAll];
    cond[a_, b_] := Condition @@ Hold[a, b];
    cond[a_] := a;

    dv = DownValues[h];
    rls = Cases[dv, (L_ :> Verbatim[Condition][R_, C_] | R_) :> cond[L, C] -> i++];
    AppendTo[rls, _ -> {}];

    dv[[ Replace[Unevaluated[expr], rls] ]]
  ]
```

Test:

```
abs[N@I] // capture
```

> ```
> HoldPattern[abs[n_?NumberQ]] :> Sign[n] n
> ```

Right-hand-side condition:

```
foo[a_] := bar /; a

foo[True]  // capture
foo[False] // capture
```

> ```
> HoldPattern[foo[a_]] :> bar /; a
>
> {}
> ```