# How to verbalise code in Mathematica?

Tags: education

How do you read an expression like?

```
x + y /. x -> 2
```

Looking up /. and -> in Mathematica docs it says ReplaceAll and Rule. But you would not pronounce the expression above as

```
x plus y replace all x rule 2.
```

Instead you would say something like

```
x plus y where x goes to two.
```

The operators /. and -> are just two examples, there are a lot of others in Mathematica. Is there some resource that addresses pronunciations in Mathematica.

Comment: @C.E Of course there must be several ways to pronounce an expression, depending on the context. I am not after one true way to pronounce, but more a list of examples how you could pronounce some not obvious expressions. Maybe no one thinks this is worthwhile and that's OK, but if anybody has discussed this I would like a link to it.

Comment: This is a topic in any programming language, as they have not been designed to become acoustic streams. Are you primarily interested in communicating vocally to other people, or are you interested in clarifying your inner monologue while working on code? Some of us are more visual-oriented and a symbol like `->` never makes it beyond the visual stage, never becomes an acoustic event.

Comment: @Roman I am primarily interested in communicating vocally to other people. When it comes to other  programming languages there is some discussion, see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746894/are-there-pronounceable-names-for-common-haskell-operators/16801782#16801782

Comment: I know that pronunciations are opinion based and that there are no true answers, but still it makes sense to me that have some way of communication vocally to other people when the need arises, so the discussion in Haskell was of great help to me, even though it is opinion based.

Comment: How about you get a list started, like the Haskell example, and everybody chips in? Something like a table with three columns: "symbol", "pronounciations" (many lines), and "voters" where everybody can put in their name to vote for a particular pronounciation.

Comment: Interesting question.  I am not in the habit of reading out code this way.  I think in this case I would say: "in x plus y, replace all x with two" – does that seem intelligible to you?

Comment: Clearly, the 'right' way to say it is `Speak@HoldForm[x + y /. x -> 2]`.  I find it interesting that `Speak` translates `->` well but has no understanding of what `/.` is.

Comment: Haha @bobthechemist it looks like this topic hasn't gotten the deep attention at WR that other topics get! `Speak@HoldForm[x -> 2]` is "x goes to 2", but `Speak@HoldForm[x :> 2]` is "x colon goes to 2" instead of something more human like "x will go to 2". I think a collection of everybody's ideas would be a good thing to assemble.

Comment: `In[127]:= SpokenString[Hold[x + y /. x -> 2]]

Out[127]= "Hold of the quantity x plus y slash dot x goes to 2"` Gould be a hair better on that "slash dot".

Comment: Why is this question closed? There are already two good answers!

Comment: I agree, I would like to see this question re-opened. I think there is enough commonality for answers to not necessarily be "entirely opinion based".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Starting a brain dump of ideas, listening to my inner monologue. Please feel free to edit and add suggestions. [Here is a list](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) of most operators.

```
| sym  | example     | pronunciation                       | votes, comments, rants
|––––––|–––––––––––––|–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––|–––––––––––––––––––––––––
| ::   | x::y        | x says y                            |
| #    | #           | slot                                |
|      | #3          | slot 3                              |
| ##   | ##          | all slots                           |
|      | ##3         | all slots from third                |
| &    | x&          | x done                              |
|      |             | x end-of-function                   |
| %    | %           | above                               |
|      |             | answer                              |
|      |             | previous                            |
| :    | x:_         | x-pattern                           |
|      |             | anything, call it x                 |
| /;   | x_/;y       | x-pattern that y                    |
|      |             | anything that y, call it x          |
| ?    | x_?yQ       | x-pattern that is y                 |
|      |             | anything y, call it x               |
| _    | x_          | x-pattern                           |
|      |             | anything, call it x                 |
| _    | x_y         | x-pattern of type y                 |
|      |             | anything of type y, call it x       |
| __   | x__         | x-patterns                          |
|      |             | any sequence, call it x             |
| ___  | x___        | x-maybepatterns                     |
|      |             | any sequence, even empty, call it x |
| _.   | x_.         | x-defaultpattern                    |
|      |             | anything, call it x, with default   |
| :    | x_:y        | x-pattern defaults to y             |
|      |             | anything, call it x, with default y |
| ..   | x..         | one or more x                       |
|      |             | x-more                              |
| ...  | x...        | zero or more x                      |
|      |             | x-maybemore                         |
| {}   | {1,2,3}     | list of 1, 2, 3                     |
| [[]] | x[[i]]      | element i of x                      |
| ;;   | x;;y;;z     | from x to y in steps of z           |
| ==   | x==y        | x equal to y                        |
| !=   | x!=y        | x not equal to y                    |
| ===  | x===y       | x same as y                         |
| =!=  | x=!=y       | x not same as y                     |
| ++   | x++         | x and then increment it             |
|      |             | x-before-increment                  |
| ++   | ++x         | x but increment it first            |
|      |             | x-after-increment                   |
| --   | x--         | x and then decrement it             |
|      |             | x-before-decrement                  |
| --   | --x         | x but decrement it first            |
|      |             | x-after-decrement                   |
| []   | f[x]        | f of x                              |
|      | f[x,y]      | f of x and y                        |
| @*   | x@*y        | y then x (read from right to left)  |
|      |             | x of y                              |
| //   | x//y        | x then y                            |
| /*   | x/*y        | x then y                            |
| @    | f@x         | f of x                              |
| ~    | x~f~y       | f of x and y                        |
|      |             | x with/using f on y                 |
| /@   | f/@x        | f mapped on x                       |
|      |             | f of all in x                       |
| //@  | f//@x       | f map-alled on x                    |
|      |             | f of everything in x                |
|      |             | f mapped on everything in x         |
| @@   | f@@x        | f-head on x                         |
|      |             | f applied to x                      |
| @@@  | f@@@x       | f-head mapped on x                  |
|      |             | f applied to all in x               |
| ->   | x->y        | x becomes y                         |
|      |             | x goes to y                         |
| :>   | x:>y        | x will become y                     |
|      |             | x will go to y                      |
| /.   | x/.y        | x where y                           |
| //.  | x//.y       | x where repeatedly y                |
| =    | x=y         | x is y                              |
| :=   | x:=y        | x will be y                         |
| ^=   | x[y]^=z     | y remembers x[y] is z               |
| ^:=  | x[y]^:=z    | y remembers x[y] will be z          |
| /:   | x/:y=z      | x remembers y is z                  |
| /:   | x/:y:=z     | x remembers y will be z             |
| .    | x=.         | x is cleared                        |
|––––––|–––––––––––––|–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––|–––––––––––––––––––
```

Comment: thank you for a nice beginning. I often pronounce x_ as "anything, call it x". I guess you could  pronounce x__ as "any sequence, call it x".  And maybe you could  pronounce x___ as "any sequence including empty, call it x".

Comment: As I spend a fair amount of time teaching Mathematica to students who have never done programming, having a list of terms to use for the language's typography - if only to be self-consistent - is very helpful.

Comment: @bobthechemist please feel free to add the way you would pronounce things to the list! I teach Mathematica too and would be keen to have a consistent list.

Comment: Do you have _h in your table? It represents any expression having the h as its head. For instance  f[x_Integer] :=... defines a function that takes any integer as a parameter. I would pronounce x_Integer as "any integer call it x".

Comment: Yes @BobUeland I had extrapolated your earlier comment to include `x_y` as "anything of type y, call it x".

Comment: I think until a universal convention manages to emerge, there will be differences of personal taste. Personally, I prefer to keep the names I use close to the command names, e.g. read `x /. y` as "x replace-all y" or "x ReplaceAll y". Less cognitive load, reinforces learning the names of the functions. Doesn't work for syntax that are not commands, e.g. `x // y` for which your "x then y" is good. I'm sure if I wrote out my verbals habits, some folks would dislike some of my suggestions. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 please free to add yours, let's make an inclusive list of alternatives!

Answer (score 27):

You could try using [`SpokenString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpokenString):

```
SpokenString[HoldForm[x + y /. x->2]]
```

> "x plus y slash dot x goes to 2"

**Addendum**

If you don't mind messing with internal functions, it is possible to customize the output of [`SpokenString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpokenString). For this purpose, it is convenient to make use of my [ExtractDownValues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154095/45431) function reproduced below:

```
SetAttributes[ExtractDownValues, HoldAll]

ExtractDownValues[sym_[args__]] := ExtractDownValues[sym,args]
ExtractDownValues[sym_,args__] := Cases[
    DownValues[sym],_[h_,_] /; MatchQ[Unevaluated[sym[args]],h]
]
```

The internal function that does most of the heavy lifting is `` SpokenStringDump`SSText ``:

```
TracePrint[SpokenString[HoldForm[x + y /. x -> 2]], _SpokenStringDump`SSText]
```

> SpokenStringDump`SSText[x+y/. x->2]
>
> SpokenStringDump`SSText[x+y]
>
> SpokenStringDump`SSText[x]
>
> SpokenStringDump`SSText[y]
>
> SpokenStringDump`SSText[2]
>
> SpokenStringDump`SSText[x->2]
>
> SpokenStringDump`SSText[x]
>
> SpokenStringDump`SSText[2]
>
> "x plus y slash dot x goes to 2"

Using `ExtractDownValues` we find:

```
ExtractDownValues @ SpokenStringDump`SSText[x + y /. x -> 2]
```

> {HoldPattern[
>      SpokenStringDump`SSText[SpokenStringDump`a_ /. SpokenStringDump`b_]] :> 
>     SpokenStringDump`SpeakQuantity[SpokenStringDump`a, ReplaceAll, True] ~~ 
>      " slash dot " ~~ 
>      If[ListQ[Unevaluated[SpokenStringDump`b]], 
>       SpokenStringDump`SpeakListContents[SpokenStringDump`b], 
>       SpokenStringDump`SpeakQuantity[SpokenStringDump`b, ReplaceAll, True]], 
>    HoldPattern[
>      SpokenStringDump`SSText[SpokenStringDump`f_[SpokenStringDump`a___]]] :> 
>     Module[{SpokenStringDump`ans = 
>        SpokenStringDump`SSText0[SpokenStringDump`f[SpokenStringDump`a]]}, 
>      If[Head[SpokenStringDump`ans] =!= SpokenStringDump`SSText0 && ! 
>         MemberQ[SpokenStringDump`ans, $Failed, {0, 1}], SpokenStringDump`ans, 
>       SpokenStringDump`SSTextFallThrough[
>        Unevaluated[SpokenStringDump`f[SpokenStringDump`a]]]]]}

Notice the " slash dot " string. So, modifying this downvalue to:

```
SpokenStringDump`SSText[a_ /.  b_] := SpokenStringDump`SpeakQuantity[a,ReplaceAll,True] ~~ 
    " where " ~~ 
    If[ListQ[Unevaluated[b]],
        SpokenStringDump`SpeakListContents[b],
        SpokenStringDump`SpeakQuantity[b,ReplaceAll,True]
    ]
```

will produce:

```
SpokenString[HoldForm[x + y /. x->2]]
```

> "x plus y where x goes to 2"