# Is it possible to write an expression A such that Evaluate[Evaluate[A]] is different from Evaluate[A]?

Tags: evaluation, core-language

Mathematica is cool for all sorts of "magic tricks", but I'm trying to get an idea on how the core term-rewriting system works. Is it possible to make a term such that the output of its evaluation can be further evaluated into something else, without additional rules being added?

Comment: You might also be interested in this [one-ste evaluation QA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-do-i-evaluate-only-one-step-of-an-expression). Notice that the result is still wrapped in `HoldForm`. It is not possible to return a result that would change if given as input again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible. Mathematica always keeps evaluating the expression for as long as any transformation rules apply.  I suggest you [read this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressionsOverview.html).

Someone might mention [`Defer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html).

`Defer[1+1]` outputs something that *looks like* `1+1`. If you select the output cell and press shift-enter, it evaluates to 2.

This *seems* like what you are asking for, but in reality, it is just some trickery with how things are stored in a notebook. It is specific to notebooks. It is not possible to reproduce it in command-line mode or to use it for working with partial results inside of a function.

Whenever Mathematica produces an output to be shown as a cell, it is converted into [boxes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheRepresentationOfTextualForms.html) which are just a representation of what is *displayed* in notebooks. Everything in a notebook is made of boxes. The expression you type in an input cell is made of boxes. Before sending it to the kernel for evaluation, the boxes are translated into a proper Mathematica expression. You can always look at the box form of a cell by pressing Command-Shift-E.

Now `Defer` does not evaluate at all.  `Defer[1+1]` behaves exactly the same as `Hold[1+1]` as far as the kernel is concerned. But `Defer[1+1]` converts into the same boxes as `1+1`. When converting back, the information that `Defer` was ever there is lost. Only `1+1` remains. For this to work, it is necessary to actually *display* the output of `Defer` in a notebook and trigger the conversion to boxes. If you simply do `x = Defer[1+1]` then `FullForm[x]` will show `Defer[1+1]`.

To sum up, `Defer` is not about evaluation but about creating a certain kind of output cell.