# How to get function to 'expand' while inactivating inner functions

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

***This is sort of a two question problem:***

**Question 1**

So I have a function as follows

```
f[x_] := x + 2;
```

I want a way to have a statement such as:

```
f[1]
```

to output as follows:

```
(* output: 1+2 *)
```

I thought the expression below would work:

```
Inactivate[f[1], Except[f]]
```

but it appears Inactivate doesn't work on the inner functions that make up the definition of f. Instead I get:

```
(* output: 3 *)
```

This makes sense to me, however is there a function/expression that can do what I'm trying to do? Call it:

```
ExpandFunction[f[1]]
(* output: 1+2 *)
```

**Question 2**

In addition, to go a step further, is there a way of making it so that the symbols in the definition of f do not get replaced? That is to say:

```
y=1;
f[x_] := x + 2;
StopSubstitutionsButExpandFunction[f[y]]
(* output: y+1 *)
```

Ideally, then, if this is possible, we could have a recursive behavior where, say:

```
z=3;
f[x_]:=x+1;
g[y_]:=f[y]*2;
StopSubstitutionsButExpandFunction[g[z]]
(* output: f[z]*2 *)
StopSubstitutionsButExpandFunction[g[z],2]
(* output: (z+1)*2 *)
```

Again, my thought was that a HoldAll attribute would work, for example:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
y = 1;
f[x_] := x + 2;
Inactivate[f[y], Except[f]]
```

Expected:

```
(* output: y+2 *)
```

Actual:

```
(* output: 3 *)
```

Comment: At least for your first question, you can use the [step](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/45431) function by @Mr.Wizard.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
f[x_] := x + HoldForm[2];

f[1]
```

yields 1+2

```
f[z]
```

yields z+2

Further,

```
g[y_] := HoldForm[f[y]]*2;

g[z]
```

returns 2 f[z]

If you need then to calculate with these functions use `ReleaseHold` first.

Have fun!