# Accessing already defined Symbols in a function

Tags: evaluation

I'd a like a function that assigns variables based on a rule list.  That is,

```
SetParameters[{x->1, y->2}]
```

would set `x=1` and `y=2`.  The problem is when `x` and `y` already have values, this understandably leads to `Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 1.` errors.  Is there a way around this using non-standard evaluation?

My attempt so far, which doesn't work:

```
Clear[SetParameters];
SetAttributes[SetParameters, HoldAll];
SetParameters[rulelist_] := Module[{vars},
  vars = Unevaluated[rulelist][[All, 1]];
  Print[vars];
  Set[Evaluate@vars, rulelist[[All, 2]]];
]
```

*Additional wrinkle:*

@J.M.'s suggestion in the comments answered my original question, but afterwards I uncovered a complication: What if I want to define the rulelist ahead of time? E.g., `rl = {x->1, y->2}; SetParameters[rl]` Any way to make that work?

Comment: Try `SetAttributes[SetParameters, HoldAll]; SetParameters[rulelist : {__Rule}] := Set @@@ Unevaluated[rulelist]` and report back.

Comment: @J.M. Yep, that seems to work.  Very simple, thanks!

Comment: @J.M. BTW, I figured out that you can suppress the output by wrapping the right-hand side in `()`.

Comment: @J.M. A complication: what if I want to define the rulelist ahead of time?  E.g., `rl = {x->1, y->2}; SetParameters[rl]`  Any way to make that work?

Comment: That sounds like a good extension to this question. Since it hasn't been answered yet, it'd be kosher to edit your question with the additional stipulation.

Comment: @J.M. Good idea, I've added it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use Mr.Wizard's  [step[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447) function for the most generality.

```
(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447 *)
step // ClearAll;
SetAttributes[step, HoldAll]
step[expr_] := Module[{P}, P = (P = Return[#, TraceScan] &) &;
   TraceScan[P, expr, TraceDepth -> 1]];

setParameters // ClearAll;
SetAttributes[setParameters, HoldAll];
setParameters[rulelist : {__Rule}] :=
    Hold[rulelist;] /. Rule -> Set // ReleaseHold;
setParameters[rulelist_] := With[{r = step[rulelist]},
   setParameters @@ r /; Head[r] === HoldForm];
```

Examples:

```
Clear[x, y];
rl = {x -> 1, y -> 2};
setParameters[rl]
{x, y}
(*  {1, 2}  *)

Clear[x, y, foo];
x = 1; y = 2;
foo[a_, b_] := {x -> a, y -> b};
setParameters[foo[11, 22]]
{x, y}
(*  {11, 22}  *)

Clear[nada, rien];
nada = rien;
setParameters[nada]
(*  setParameters[rien]  *)
```

Comment: An alternative to `step[]`, but not as general: `setParameters[rulelist_Symbol] := With[{r = Hold[rulelist] /. OwnValues[rulelist]},   setParameters @@ r /; Hold[rulelist] =!= r];`

Comment: I can't get the alternative in your comment to work (just returns unevaluated) but the main answer in the text seems perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisK It should work for `rl` but not for `foo[11, 12]`. That's the "not as general" restriction.  You also need the `setParameters[rulelist : {__Rule}] := 
 Hold[rulelist;] /. Rule -> Set // ReleaseHold;` def. to go with the `OwnValues` one in my first comment.

Comment: Got it, that was the part I was missing.