# Using Unevaluated to get a list of symbol names

Tags: core-language, hold

The [official documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) of `Unevaluated` contains the following example:

```
SetAttributes[symbolLength, HoldAll];
symbolLength[s_Symbol] := StringLength[SymbolName[Unevaluated[s]]];

ClearAll[myvar];
myvar = 42;
symbolLength[myvar] (* Output: 5 *)
```

But I am unable to extend this example to a list. The following toy function does not work:

```
ClearAll[fn1];
SetAttributes[fn1, HoldAll];
fn1[args : {__Symbol}] := Map[SymbolName /* StringLength] @ Unevaluated[args];

ClearAll[a, bc, def];
{a, bc, def} = {10, 20, 30};
fn1[{a, bc, def}]
(*
    ERROR
    SymbolName: Argument 10 at position 1 is expected to be a symbol.
    StringLength: String expected at position 1 in StringLength[SymbolName[10]].
*)
```

What is the trick I am missing?

Comment: Try `StringLength /@ SymbolName /@ Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated[args]`

Comment: Or use `Listable`.

Comment: Look at: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-do-i-evaluate-only-one-step-of-an-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later in the documentation you'll encounter this:

> Unevaluated works only where it appears; it is not propagated:

What this means is that as soon as the evaluation engine encounters the `Unevaluated` expression a second time, the `Unevaluated` gets stripped. For example, if you evaluate just this,

```
Unevaluated[{a, bc, def}]
```

the output will be `Unevaluated[{a, bc, def}]`. If you evaluate this,

```
z = Unevaluated[{a, bc, def}]
```

the output will be `{10, 20, 30}`, but that's not actually what `OwnValues[z]` is--it's what you get after the evaluation engine does the replacement for `z` and then continues evaluating:

```
OwnValues[z]
```

is actually `{HoldPattern[z] :> {a, bc, def}}`. The `Unevaluated` was stripped, but since it found itself inside of a `SetDelayed`, the `a`, `bc`, `def` are still held and not immediately evaluated.

The "tricks" have been provided in the comments. You can propogate the `Unevaluated` yourself by mapping it over your `Unevaluated` list.

```
fn1[args : {__Symbol}] := StringLength /@ SymbolName /@ Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated[args]
(*suggested by @LukasLang*)
```

The outer `Unevaluated` will be immediately stripped to do the mapping but each element will now be wrapped in `Unevaluated`. Those new `Unevaluated`s will be stripped (but no further evaluation will occur yet) once `SymbolName` is applied, which is what you want at that point.

Or, you can make `fn1` Listable, as @Kuba suggested. This means that the function you define will automatically be applied to each element of a list when a list is passed as the argument. To be clear, in that case you'd define `fn1` for a single argument:

```
SetAttributes[fn1, {HoldAll, Listable}];
fn1[arg_Symbol] := StringLength[SymbolName[Unevaluated[arg]]]
```